# Adding two matrices in python

Tags: python-3.3

```
def addM(a, b):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        row = []
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            row.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
        res.append(row)
    return res
```

I found this code here which was made by @Petar Ivanov, this code adds two matrices, i really don't understand the 3rd line, why does he use len(a) and the 5th line, why does he use len(a[0]). In the 6th line, also why is it a[i][j] +b[i][j]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix here is a list of lists, for example a 2x2 matrix will look like: `a=[[0,0],[0,0]]`. Then it is easy to see:

1. `len(a)` - number of rows.
2. `len(a[0])` - number of columns (since this is a matrix, the length of `a[0]` is the same as length of any `a[i]`).
3. This way, `i` is the number of row, `j` is the number of column and `a[i][j]+b[i][j]` is simply adding up the elements of two matrices which are placed in the same locations in the matrices.

For all this to work, `a` and `b` should be of the same shapes (so, numbers of rows and columns would match).

Comment: if they are not the same (matrices) will i get an error or do i have to modify the code in order to return none?

if len(a) != len(b):
    return None

Comment: @user2971015 It would certainly be a good idea to handle `len(a)!=len(b) or len(a[0])!=len(b[0])` to be sure the input is right. You also need to check if all the row lengths for each of `a` and `b` are the same, otherwise they won't be considered matrices.